# Find HTML Tags in Properties

Tags: xpath, aem, crx

My current issue is to find HTML-Tags inside of property values. I thought it would be easy to search with a query like `/jcr:root/content/xgermany//*[jcr:contains(., '<strong>')] order by @jcr:score`

It looks like there is a problem with the chars `<` and `>` because this query finds everything which has `strong` in it's property. It finds `<strong>Some Text</strong>` but also `This is a strong man`.

Also the [Query Builder API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html) didn't helped me.

Is there a possibility to solve it with a XPath or SQL Query or do I have to iterate through the whole content?

Comment: What happens if you try `/jcr:root/content/xgermany//strong`, or `/jcr:root/content/xgermany//*[local-name() = 'strong']`?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. I think it's because I am searching for property values. I adjusted the question to make that more clear.

Comment: You had already made that clear... it was just my ignorance about JCR and so on. Thanks for making it clearer though.

Comment: One thing you could try is replacing `<` with `&lt;` in your query: `/jcr:root/content/xgermany//*[jcr:contains(., '&lt;strong>')]`. Not sure if that will help.

Comment: With HTML escaped characters it finds no result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why it finds `This is a strong man` as a result for `'<strong>'`, but it sounds like the unexpected behavior comes from the ["simple search-engine syntax" for the second argument to jcr:contains()](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/1.0/6.6.5.2_jcr_contains_Function.html). Apparently the `<` `>` are just being ignored as "meaningless" punctuation.

You could try quoting the search term:

```
/jcr:root/content/xgermany//*[jcr:contains(., '"<strong>"')]
```

though you may have to tweak that if your whole XPath expression is enclosed in double quotes.

Of course this will not be very robust even if it works, since you're trying to find HTML elements by searching for fixed strings, instead of actually parsing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an specific jcr:primaryType and the targeted properties you can do something like this

```
 select * from nt:unstructured where text like '%<strong>%'
```

I tested it , but you need to know the properties you are intererested in.

This is jcr-sql syntax

Answer (score 0):

Start using predicates like a champ this way all of this will make sense to you!

```
HTML Encode &lt;strong&gt;
HTML Decimal &#60;strong&#62;
```

Query builder is your friend:
Predicates: (like a CHAMP!)

```
path=/content/geometrixx
type=nt:unstructured
property=text
property.operation=like
property.value=%&#60;strong&#62;%
```

Have go here:
[http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?*charset*=UTF-8&query=path%3D%2Fcontent%2Fgeometrixx%0D%0Atype%3Dnt%3Aunstructured%0D%0Aproperty%3Dtext%0D%0Aproperty.operation%3Dlike%0D%0Aproperty.value%3D%25%3Cstrong%3E%25](http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?_charset_=UTF-8&query=path%3D%2Fcontent%2Fgeometrixx%0D%0Atype%3Dnt%3Aunstructured%0D%0Aproperty%3Dtext%0D%0Aproperty.operation%3Dlike%0D%0Aproperty.value%3D%25%3Cstrong%3E%25)

Predicates: (like a CHAMP!)

```
path=/content/geometrixx
type=nt:unstructured
property=text
property.operation=like
property.value=%&lt;strong&gt;%
```

Have a go here:

[http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?*charset*=UTF-8&query=path%3D%2Fcontent%2Fgeometrixx%0D%0Atype%3Dnt%3Aunstructured%0D%0Aproperty%3Dtext%0D%0Aproperty.operation%3Dlike%0D%0Aproperty.value%3D%25%26lt%3Bstrong%26gt%3B%25](http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?_charset_=UTF-8&query=path%3D%2Fcontent%2Fgeometrixx%0D%0Atype%3Dnt%3Aunstructured%0D%0Aproperty%3Dtext%0D%0Aproperty.operation%3Dlike%0D%0Aproperty.value%3D%25%26lt%3Bstrong%26gt%3B%25)

XPath:

```
/jcr:root/content/geometrixx//element(*, nt:unstructured)
[
jcr:like(@text, '%<strong>%') 
]
```

SQL2 (already covered... NASTY YUK..)

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:unstructured] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/content/geometrixx]) and text like '%<strong>%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm sure it's entirely possible with a string of predicates, it's possibly heading down the wrong route. Ideally it would be better to parse the HTML when it is stored or published. 
The required information would be stored on simple properties on the node in question. The query will then be a lot simpler with just a property = value query, than lots of overly complex query syntax.
It will probably be faster too.
So if you read in your HTML with something like HTMLClient and then parse it with a OSGI service, that can accurately save these properties for you. Every time the HTML is changed the process would update these properties as necessary. Just some thoughts if your SQL is getting too much.